# Redirecting with nginx redirects to localhost in Windows

Tags: windows, apache, redirect, nginx

I am trying to redirect my dns to ip through nginx via its config file and file in sites-enabled folder, 
But it is always redirect to nginx homepage showing 'Welcome to nginx!'.

My configuration files include:

**NGINX.CONF**

```
 user  www-data www-data;
    worker_processes  4;

    #error_log  logs/error.log;
    #error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
    #error_log  logs/error.log  info;

    pid        var/run/nginx.pid;


    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }


    http {
        include       mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;
        include /conf/*.conf;
        include /conf/sites-enabled/*;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;
    tcp_nodelay    on;
    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable    "msie6";

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  fe.paytm.com;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {`enter code here`
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}
    }
```

**conf file inside sites-enabled folder**

```
 server {  
     server_name   my.domain.com; 
      root C:/Users/some/absolute-path/public;
      index index.html index.htm; 

     access_log /var/log/nginx/my-domain.access.log; 
      error_log  /var/log/nginx/my-domain.error.log; 
      underscores_in_headers on; 
      location /   {  
         root C:/Users/some/absolute-path/public;      
         proxy_pass http://localhost:8997;
      }
    }
```

The host entry for the ip is also done:

```
 127.0.0.1  my.domain.com
```

What is there that I am missing or doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to add `listen 80` in your configuration. Due to which nginx is using default.conf and showing "Welcome to nginx!"
The updated configuration would look like this:

```
server {  
  listen 80;
  server_name   my.domain.com; 
  root C:/Users/some/absolute-path/public;
  index index.html index.htm; 

  access_log /var/log/nginx/my-domain.access.log; 
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/my-domain.error.log; 
  underscores_in_headers on; 
  location /   {  
     root C:/Users/some/absolute-path/public;      
     proxy_pass http://localhost:8997;
  }
}
```

Comment: now instead of showing homepage it has started giving Page Not Found error..... what next can be done ..

Comment: Yes, it means now nginx is detecting the request and serving using above configuration. Most probably it might not be able to find access_log/error_log path as they are linux based and root Windows based. Kindly fix them according to your requirement, it should work fine. Please comment if it is still having problem (after path changed to windows based)